# Google Calendar API Endpoints

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Im trying to build a calendar into a web application that would simply display a single user's events.

Im simply trying to access the API by hitting the endpoints but having issues with authentication.

**I am using the following endpoint to grab the data:**

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_id}?key={api_key}`

I have created an API key using the dev console.

**I get the following JSON in return:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I am able to get the data using API explorer in the dev console but I have to Login/Authorize. I would like the calendar app to be viewable by all users without having to log in or anything. Isnt that what the API Key is for??

How to do I simply hit my endpoint and get my data while authenticating implicitly?

Comment: Not sure, but the API key is not the only obligation. You have to get a token access from Google, and pass it in your header : `bearer $token_access`

Comment: Simply put, API keys do not provide sufficient security as described in this [post](http://nordicapis.com/why-api-keys-are-not-enough/). It's open to accidental exposure among other things. That's why Google APIs require the [use of OAuth flow when making calls to their APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). So in your case, you need to use OAuth Login. Also, try looking into [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).